# New to creating GUIs. How would I combine text area and radio buttons

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jtextarea

I understand how to create radio buttons and I understand how to create a text area. What I have trouble with is combing the two onto one frame.

Can anyone help me or show me how to do so? Do I have to layout a grid with boarders?

Here I was trying to follow my text book on ways to combine the two but I sort of failed. :(
I've tried other ways but none have worked for me. When I attempt to do the text area and radio buttons separately, they work.
This isn't my final code. My finish product should allow me to keep track of how many times a certain student is picked, like a vote, and printing out the totals in the text area each time.

Getting this part to work will help me further advance in my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class AsnTwo extends JFrame
   {
      private JRadioButton jrbS1 = new JRadioButton("Student 1");
      private JRadioButton jrbS2 = new JRadioButton("Student 2");
      private JRadioButton jrbS3 = new JRadioButton("Student 3");

      private JTextArea jtaT = new JTextArea("Hello");


      public static void main(String[] args)
         {
            AsnTwo frame = new AsnTwo();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setTitle("Assignment Two");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
         }

      public AsnTwo()
         {
            JPanel jpTextArea = new JPanel();
            jpTextArea.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
            jtaT.setEditable(false);
            jtaT.setLineWrap(true);
            jtaT.setText("Something");
            add(jpTextArea, BorderLayout.EAST);

            JPanel jpRadioButtons = new JPanel();
            jpRadioButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
            jpRadioButtons.add(jrbS1);
            jpRadioButtons.add(jrbS2);
            jpRadioButtons.add(jrbS3);
            add(jpRadioButtons, BorderLayout.WEST);//Adds buttons to GUI

            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            group.add(jrbS1);
            group.add(jrbS2);
            group.add(jrbS3);


         }

      public void printTextField(String text)
         {
            jtaT.setText("Hello");
         } 
   }
```

Comment: Do you have a rough sketch of what you are trying to do?  I can think off a half dozen ways to mix the two, but would need more context of what you are trying to do before I knew which approaches might help...

Comment: Sorry, I should have added in my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I got it. I just had to change

add(jpTextArea, BorderLayout.EAST);

to

add(jtaT, BorderLayout.EAST);